# Delete Table Rows Based On Two Field Values

Tags: arcpy, cursor, table, delete

How can I delete a row in a table if value A from Field 1 does not match value B from Field 4 ?

I attempted to use code from a previous post as I figured it would be a start but didn't work.

[image]

```
import arcpy
shp = r"C:\path\to\your\shapefile.shp"
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(shp, "", "", "some_field")
for row in rows:
    if row.some_field == 2:
        rows.deleteRow(row)
del row
del rows
```

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152481/how-to-delete-selected-rows-using-arcpy

Comment: Im a newbie with ArcPy so would the does not equal be written as so?                          import arcpy

fc = r'C:\temp\test.gdb\tmp'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "Value_1","Value_4") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] <> row[1]:
            cursor.deleteRow()

Comment: If that doesn't work use `row[0] != row[1]`

Comment: Your second parameter needs to be a list of field names.  Right now you have a field name referenced in both the second and third parameter.  (fc, ["Value_1", "Value_2"])

Answer (score 4):

I would begin by creating a copy of the original feature class. Then it is simply a matter of checking if `row[0]` (i.e. Value_1 field) is equivalent to `row[1]` (Value_4 field). Try the following approach:

```
import arcpy

in_shp = r"C:\path\to\your\shapefile.shp"
shp_copy = r"C:\path\to\your\shapefile_v2.shp"

# Make a copy!
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_shp, shp_copy)

# Check if "Value_1" is equivalent to "Value_4", if not delete row
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shp_copy, ["Value_1", "Value_4"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] != row[1]:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: I attempted script and added image of error. Does it matter that its a table and not a shapefile?

Comment: @huskersila You need to make sure to name the copy different than the original.

Comment: ty for the help .... I ended up getting one of the above scripts to work... ty again for your time! much appreciated!!                                                  import arcpy


fc = r'C:\Users\FILEPATH'



with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,["VALUE_1","VALUE_4"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] != row[1]:
            cursor.deleteRow()

Comment: @huskersila if this has worked for you please mark as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\Users\FILEPATH'
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["VALUE_1","VALUE_4"]) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    if row[0] != row[1]:
      cursor.deleteRow()
```